# How to solve gdb error in sourced command file with gbdinit file?

Tags: gdb

all. I am trying to solve an error that is coming up on my gdb version. When I type gdb in command line I get:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 13.1
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin22.6.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
/Users/cdwalke8/.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file:
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb)
```

Notice that it states `/Users/cdwalke8/.gdbinit:1: Error in sourced command file: No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`

When I go and look at this file, this is what is inside:

```
set startup-with-shell-off
```

What does this mean and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am silly...

The command should be

`set startup-with-shell off`